# Why is it faster to run a query via a linked server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that a vendor wants to start running on my data warehouse.   The version I'm posting runs at 18 seconds if I run via a linked server (SQL Server 2017, 12GB RAM, more CPU) as a remote query, and 4 minutes if I run it directly on the server (4GB RAM, SQL Server 2008).

Yes, I know my servers suck. We are getting a better set.

**Question:** Why would it be faster to run this:

```
    select * from [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[RegAcct_Main]
```

than going directly onto the server eih-dr01 and running this:

```
    select * from RegAcct_main
```

Here's the big, bad query, for reference:

```
    declare @start datetime 
    set @start = dateadd(minute, -45, getdate())

    SELECT 
     'AST' AS [HDR]
    ,RAM.Facility_MisFacID AS [FID]
    ,MRN.PrefixMedicalRecordNumber AS [MRN]
    ,RAM.AccountNumber AS [VISIT_NBR]
    ,MDSM.[Name] AS [CATEGORY]
    ,PADM.MisDocumentationSectionOid AS [CATEGORY_ID]
    ,MQM.Text
    ,MDSQ.QuestionMnemonic
    --,COALESCE(MQM.Text,MDSQ.QuestionMnemonic) AS [QUESTION]
    ,PADQ.QueryValue
    --,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PADQ.QueryValue,'|}',''),'{',''),'}',''),'|',',') AS [FINDING]
    ,PADM.DateTimePerformed
    --,CONVERT(VARCHAR,PADM.DateTimePerformed,101) + ' ' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,PADM.DateTimePerformed,108),5) AS [REPORT_DT]
    --,PADM.DateTimePerformed
    --,1 AS Ord

    FROM [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[PcsAcctAct_IntActAssessments] PAAIAA

    INNER JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[RegAcct_Main] RAM
    ON PAAIAA.SourceID = RAM.SourceID
    AND PAAIAA.VisitID = RAM.VisitID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[MisFac_Main] MFM
    ON RAM.SourceID = MFM.SourceID
    AND RAM.Facility_MisFacID = MFM.MisFacID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[MisHimDept_Main] MHDM
    ON MHDM.SourceID = MFM.SourceID
    AND MHDM.MisHimDeptID = MFM.HimDepartment_MisHimDeptID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[HimRec_MedicalRecordNumbers] MRN
    ON RAM.SourceID = MRN.SourceID
    AND RAM.PatientID = MRN.PatientID
    AND MHDM.MedicalRecordNumberPrefix = MRN.MrnPrefixID

    INNER JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[PcsAssmntData_Main] PADM
    ON PAAIAA.SourceID = PADM.SourceID
    AND PAAIAA.VisitID + '{A^' + PAAIAA.InterventionActivityAssessment_MisDocSectID + '}' = PADM.PcsAssmntDataID
    AND PAAIAA.InterventionActivityUrnID = PADM.IdentifierID

    INNER JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[PcsAssmntData_Queries] PADQ
    ON PADM.SourceID = PADQ.SourceID
    AND PADM.PcsAssmntDataID = PADQ.PcsAssmntDataID
    AND PADM.IdentifierID = PADQ.IdentifierID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[MisDocSect_Main] MDSM
    ON PADM.SourceID = MDSM.SourceID
    AND PADM.MisDocumentationSectionOid = MDSM.MisDocSectID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[MisDocSect_Questions] MDSQ
    ON PADQ.SourceID = MDSQ.SourceID
    AND PADQ.QuerySetID = MDSQ.QuestionSetUrnID
    AND PADQ.QueryNumberID = MDSQ.QuestionUrnID
    AND PADM.MisDocumentationSectionOid = MDSQ.MisDocSectID

    LEFT JOIN [eih-dr01].livefdb.[dbo].[MisQry_Main] MQM
    ON MDSQ.SourceID = MQM.SourceID
    AND MDSQ.QuestionMnemonic = MQM.MisQryID

    where 
    --RAM.AdmitDateTime 
    PADM.DateTimePerformed >= @start
    --and MDSM.[Name] = 'Vital Signs'
    and PADM.MisDocumentationSectionOid like '%VS%'
```

Comment: Perhaps some of the things in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43754/sql-server-linked-server-and-query-performance) apply to your situation? Check out the execution plans and add them to the question (http://pastetheplan.com)

Comment: [Distributed Query Deep Dive - Conor Cunningham](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Distributed_Query_Deep_Dive) has a lot of good information in it about how and where remote queries are processed. It's possible that the majority of the hard work is done on the better-equipped server. It may also be a Cardinality Estimation and plan choice issue. Without the query plans, it's impossible to say. Like asking why you eat pizza faster left handed.

Comment: Check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/large-queries-are-slower-in-ssms/77877#77877 It could be spending the extra time rendering the results on the resource limited server.